# Using rpm/grep to check whether multiple services are installed - as one liner?

Tags: centos, grep, rpm

The following code is used to check whether a service (read from variable, can be empty or up to X services named) is installed or not and take appropriate action.

```
... if ! rpm -qa | grep -qw $SERVICE; then ...
```

How can I achieve the same but allowing to set and read variables from the following formats:

Option - variables in one line separated by single space:
Example: `SERVICE=httpd mariadb mariadb-server`

Basically I want a one liner checking if the service (can be from 0 - 99) is installed.

Full Idea:

```
SERVICE=mariadb httpd

if [ "`systemctl is-active $SERVICE`" != "active" ]; then
  if ! rpm -qa | grep -qw $SERVICE; then 
    yum -y install $SERVICE;
    echo "$SERVICE has been installed.";
  else systemctl start $SERVICE && echo "$SERVICE started"; \
  fi
fi
```

Comment: It would help if you clarified whether `chkconfig` or `systemd` is used.

Comment: using systemd but don´t really understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for f in $SERVICE; do if ! rpm -qa \| grep -qw $f; then ... fi; done
```

Comment: service names and package names may be *similar*, but often differ.

Comment: True, but I'm assuming the OP can handle any differences of that nature, as that ability seems implicit in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to CentOS 6, a *service* would match one of the filenames under `/etc/rc.d/init.d`

For your purpose, ignore the occasional custom service script which does not come from an RPM, and just do

```
for f in $SERVICE; do s=/etc/rc.d/init.d/$f; [ -f "$s" ] && rpm -qf "$s"; done
```

That would check for the existence of the service file and print the name of the corresponding package.  If the service file is missing, nothing is printed.

In testing this for syntax, I made a script, setting `SERVICE` from the command-line arguments, e.g.,

```
SERVICE="$*"
```

and a sample input/output is shown:

```
$ /tmp/foo avahi-daemon blk-availability bluetooth certmonger cgconfig cgred cpusp
eed crond
avahi-0.6.25-15.el6.x86_64
lvm2-2.02.118-3.el6_7.4.x86_64
bluez-4.66-1.el6.x86_64
certmonger-0.77.5-1.el6.x86_64
libcgroup-0.40.rc1-16.el6.x86_64
libcgroup-0.40.rc1-16.el6.x86_64
cpuspeed-1.5-22.el6.x86_64
cronie-1.4.4-15.el6_7.1.x86_64
```

To do this, in your example

```
if ! rpm -qa | grep -qw $SERVICE; then
```

you would replace it with

```
if [ -z "$( rpm -qf /etc/rc.d/init.d/$SERVICE 2>/dev/null )" ] ; then
```

If the service file is missing, `rpm` will write an error message to the standard error.  If it is present, but not from an RPM, `rpm` will return a message to the standard output (which is consistent: you should not install something to replace a custom script).

For CentOS 7, using `systemd`, you can use the same idea, but with a different directory layout.  It stores ".service" files in

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/
```

which could be tested as

```
if [ -z "$( rpm -qf /usr/lib/systemd/system/${SERVICE}.service 2>/dev/null )" ] ; then
```

On my CentOS 7 machine

- there are 384 *unit-files* listed by `systemctl list-unit-files`
- 101 are disabled in the default configuration
- 275 are ".service" files
- the remainder (109) are suffixed ".mount", ".path", ".slice", ".socket", ".target"

Supposing that you checked for service names which match packages, as suggested:

- A dozen or so of the *service* names include characters which would not be used in a package name, e.g., `'@'` and `'.'`.  Just the same, search for the list of all services.
- It takes a while (about 5 minutes to process the whole list), and fails to match anything for 220 of the list (20% success).
- Many of the matches are coincidental, with multiple packages being found (count that as another 70% failure).
- Overall, that's a 5% success rate.

On the other hand, processing the list using the `rpm -qf` method takes about 30 seconds with 100% success.

Comment: Thanks again, but actually I am creating a helper (see full example in my edited post please) that is loaded into another bash file in which the service (0 or more) that needs to be checked (check if is not started, if not check if is installed at all if not install, then check if enabled and then start)

Comment: hm, it looks like it could do the job, but saying: line 1: httpd: command not found
Too few arguments.
Too few arguments.

Comment: BTW I am on CentOS 7.2 - clean install.

Comment: Perhaps a problem in your script as you adapted the change: I tested this line in a script to verify its syntax...

Comment: @frank some more data to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I am confident my initial question didn´t provide the specs in the detail you needed and that your provided solutions would work - but they do nily in parts in my case.

However, you brought me on the (for me) right path and the following does what I need - pretty sure there are better approaches but at least its working and I understand whats happening :)

Thanks for your support on this.

```
PACKAGE="mariadb-server httpd"
SERVICE="mariadb httpd"

for f in $PACKAGE
do
  if ! rpm -qa \| grep -qw ${f}
  then
    yum -y install ${f}
  fi
done

for f in $SERVICE
do
  if [ "systemctl is-active ${f}" != "active" ]
  then
    systemctl enable ${f}
    systemctl start ${f}
  fi
done
```